# MySQL Stored Procedure calls from Grails app very slow to execute

Tags: hibernate, grails

Grails Version: 3.0.7

Groovy Version: 2.4.5

JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

We've recently been experiencing a huge slow down in the execution time of stored procedures within MySQL in a Grails 3.0.7 app hosted on Heroku.  Unfortunately, this happens very sporadically.

Sometimes execution time is < 200 milliseconds but we are seeing the same stored procedures sometimes take in excess of 70,000 milliseconds.  This is the same query with the same parameters.

Can anybody explain why this may be happening in a Grails app or if there are any issues in either the code or the MySQL stored procedure shown below?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def ids = []

    StopWatch queryStopWatch = new StopWatch('advancedSearchWithPagedResults-DD-01')
    queryStopWatch.start()

    sql.eachRow("{call findEvents(?, ?, ?)}",
            [wildcardSearch, startDate, endDate], offset, max) { row ->

        // pull out the id's into a list and later use that to get grails managed objects
        ids << row.id
    }

    queryStopWatch.stop()
    log.info(queryStopWatch.toString())

    // close of the connection
    sql.close()
```

And the stored procedure:

```
BEGIN 

    SELECT DISTINCT e.*
    FROM event e
    INNER JOIN event_organiser eo on e.event_organiser_id = eo.id
    WHERE (e.event_name LIKE in_search OR e.address_town LIKE in_search OR e.address_county LIKE in_search OR eo.event_organiser_name LIKE in_search)
    AND e.start_date_time >= in_start_date
    AND e.start_date_time <= in_end_date
    AND e.enabled = true
    ORDER BY e.start_date_time;

END
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this slowdown is restricted to database interaction using MySQL stored procedures.  Importantly, I cannot replicate this in our local development environments and the problem only exists on staging/live servers hosted with Heroku/ClearDB.

Comment: I'm in talks with the database platform provider and hopefully this is a service issue as opposed to a programming issue.  I'll update here in due course.

Comment: Why don't you do this query with criteria / HQL instead of a stored procedure because the query is very small. I use a very very complex stored procedure with 750 LOC in mysql including many temp tables and have no probems with performance... P.S. maybe the connection build up and closing takes some times. Don't close the connection and use pooling, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for above comment Bernhard but I just fixed this a few hours ago.

It was down to a provider issue and the database instance being throttled in a shared environment.

I moved to a new provider in a single tenant plan and not only did query execution speed increase dramatically but the sporadic timeout issue did also.

Note : The reason I use stored process is down to the complexity of some other queries.  I decided to implement all queries in the same manner using stored process.